# How to config Postfix/Dovecot to deliver all address+anything@example.com to address@example.com

Tags: postfix, dovecot

Like Gmail how to configure Postfix/Dovecot on Ubuntu to deliver all address+anything@example.com to address@example.com?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`recipient_delimiter`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter) directive in Postfix:

```
 recipient_delimiter = +
```

There is no need to do configuration in dovecot.

Comment: not working! anything else beside it?

Comment: Reload postfix? What is the error message you get in the logs?

Comment: the email bounced back: user unknown

Comment: Please post full lines of your maillog by editing your question above.